# Most accurate open-source OCR for handwritten numbers?

Tags: open-source, numbers, ocr, handwriting

My software needs to read a fixed-length handwritten number.

While I could use a general-purpose library like [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29), I am sure there is something smarter. Tesseract will probably misinterpret some of the 1 or 7 as I or l, whereas a software that expects only numbers would not.

Knowing that there are only numbers *(American-English way of writing them)*, the algorithm could focus on 10 potential matches instead of hundreds of symbols.

Any experience OCRing handwritten number-only fields?
What open source library/software did you get the best results with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ) of Tesseract:

> **How do I recognize only digits?**
>
> In 2.03 and above:
>
> Use
>
> ```
> TessBaseAPI::SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
> ```
>
> *before* calling an Init function or put this in a text file called `tessdata/configs/digits`:
>
> ```
> tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789
> ```
>
> and then your command line becomes:
>
> ```
> tesseract image.tif outputbase nobatch digits
> ```
>
> *Warning:* Until the old and new config variables get merged, you *must* have the `nobatch` parameter too.

But I think since it was designed for printed—not handwritten—text, accuracy might suffer even for digits only.

Comment: Thanks for this!
But indeed Tesseract don't seem to be designed for handwritten stuff so it would probably be quite mediocre at it.

Comment: @nic: Maybe you could re-train it. It seems to be possible.

Comment: Seems possible indeed. But when I propose this solution to the client company, they might look at me funny... A proven solution with community (even small) would probably be more credible. I would be surprised if it does not exist already.

Comment: Now that I think about it, handwritten digits should not be really difficult to recognize... they are not linked into fuzzy words like Latin letters. Much easier to recognize than handwritten text.

Comment: @Nicolas, did you manage to find a proper solution for your use case (OCR adapted for handwritten numericals)?

Comment: @MiroslavDzhokanov: Unfortunately not. By the way, this question was off-topic here, so I recreated it at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27834/accurate-open-source-ocr-for-handwritten-numbers